# How do I get reference to the FormControl from a component that implements ControlValueAccessor?

Tags: angular

I created an Angular component derived from [this blog post](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-custom-form-controls-with-reactive-forms-and-ngmodel). I have it in a reactive form and I would like to get the errors on the form control, the component itself will have a stylized error message that it will render when the control has an error on it. However when I try to inject the NgControl class into the component I am getting circular reference issues, so how would I access the errors on the control?

Here is the current code, it's not complete yet but it should give the basic idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

```ts
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import {
    NgControl,
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    ControlValueAccessor,
    Validator,
    AbstractControl,
    FormControl,
    NG_VALIDATORS
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'form-field-input',
    templateUrl: './form-field-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form-field-input.component.less'],
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormFieldInputComponent),
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class FormFieldInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

    private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
    private propagateTouch = (_: any) => { };

    @Input('label') label: string;
    @Input('type') type: string;
    @Input('id') id: string;
    @Input('formControlName') formControlName: string;
    @Input('error') error: string;
    @Input('classes') classes: any;

    private value: string;
    private data: any;

    constructor() {
        debugger;
    }

    private onChange(event) {
        this.data = event.target.value;
        this.propagateChange(this.data);
        this.propagateTouch(this.data);
    }

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        this.data = obj;
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.propagateTouch = fn;
    }
}
```

template file:

```html
<div class="form-field-input-component">
    <input id="{{id}}"
           type="{{type}}"
           class="form-field-input"
           [value]="data"
           (change)="onChange($event)"
           (keyup)="onChange($event)" />
    <span class="context-icon fa fa-lock"></span>
    <span class="info-icon fa fa-info-circle"></span>
    <!-- I will have an NGIF here to check for errors before rendering the error -->
    <div class="form-error">
        {{ error }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping to do this through some sort of dependency injection or declarative style. Since I couldn't find anything using those methods I will share how I fixed this for my case.

I just added the formGroup as an input parameter to the components, along with the formControlName begin passed I am able to get reference to the control.

Here is the end result of my component

```
//Typescript code file for component
/// ... necessary imports
@Component({
    selector: 'form-field-input',
    templateUrl: './form-field-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form-field-input.component.less'],
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormFieldInputComponent),
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class FormFieldInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

    private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
    private propagateTouch = (_: any) => { };

    @Input('label') label: string;
    @Input('type') type: string;
    @Input('id') id: string;
    @Input('contextIconName') contextIconName: string;

    //Here I take in both the parent form and the form control name
    //in ngOnInit I throw if there is no parent form passed
    @Input('formControlName') formControlName: string;
    @Input('parentForm') parentForm: FormGroup;

    @Input('classes') classes: any;
    @Input('errorDefs') errorDefs: any;

    private error: string;
    private value: string;
    private data: any;
    private control: AbstractControl;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if (!this.parentForm) {
            throw "Form Field input component must be a part of a form group"
        }

        //It ain't pretty but here we get access to the control and all of it's errors
        this.control = this.parentForm.get(this.formControlName);
        if (!this.control) {
            throw "Form Field input component must be a part of a form group"
        }
    }

    private setError() {
        if (this.errorDefs && this.control.errors) {
            var errorKeys = Object.keys(this.control.errors).filter(x => !!x);
            if (errorKeys) {
                var errorKey = errorKeys[0];
                var error = this.errorDefs[errorKey] || null;
                this.error = error;
                return;
            }
        }
        this.error = null;
    }

    //Now on our on change event we can propagate the events 
    //To the registered handlers, which should set the form field errors
    //and at the end we can check the reference to the control for those errors
    //so that we can display the appropriate messages
    private onChange(event) {
        this.data = event ? event.target.value : this.data;
        this.propagateChange(this.data);
        this.propagateTouch(this.data);
        this.setError();
    }

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        this.data = obj;
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.propagateTouch = fn;
    }
}

//HTML template file
<div class="form-field-input-component">
    <input id="{{id}}"
           type="{{type}}"
           class="form-field-input {{class}}"
           [value]="data"
           (change)="onChange($event)"
           (keyup)="onChange($event)"
           (blur)="onChange($event)" />
    <span class="context-icon fa {{contextIconName || 'fa-cog'}}"></span>
    <span class="info-icon fa fa-info-circle" *ngIf="error"></span>
    <div class="form-field-error" *ngIf="error">
        {{ error }}
    </div>
</div>

//EXAMPLE USAGE:
<form novalidate [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
    <form-field-input
                      formControlName="firstName"
                      [parentForm]="myFormGroup"

                      <!-- example: When the Validators.required sets it's error message we can map that to a user friendly error -->
                      [errorDefs]="{
                           'required': 'this field is required' 
                      }"
                      <!-- Other inputs and stuff-->
                      >
    </form-field-input>
</form>
```

Comment: If you are passing the formGroup to your custom control, why you need ControlValueAccessor and all those implementation for custom control?
Just pass the reference of FormGroup to your parent dive of template in custom control and done. No need of any ControlValueAccessor and the  implementations .

Comment: I know I'm late to this party, but why would you want to pass a FormControl as an input? you could just encapsulate the whole logic under the child component and use ControlValueAccessor interface. In this approach, the parent component have no idea about the control internals, just the data, and the control management (validation, etc..) is being done only in one place - the child component

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just inject `ngControl` into the custom input element like this,

(ts file)

```js
import {NgControl} from "@angular/forms";

...

constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {}
```

(template)

```html
<label>Custom Input</label>
<input [formControl]="ngControl.control"/>
```

then in the parent component call it like this,

```html
<custom-input
  [formControl]="youControlHere"
  ngDefualtControl> <!-- This is the part that gives the parent control -->
</custom-input>
```

If you have this set up it should work like a normal input with formControl!
Hope this helps.

Comment: I get an cyclic dependency error: 
`ERROR in Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! NgControl`

But I also use a directive.

Comment: @JoCa Ii'm not sure of your error, did you try it not in a directive and get the same error?